# Text in button gone in :before state

Tags: html, css, button, hover

I am using the 3rd button from this [codepen](https://codepen.io/natalia-reshetnikova/pen/oRRjPP).

```
.btn {
    line-height: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 250px;
    cursor: pointer;
}    
.btn-three {
        color: #FFF;
        transition: all 0.5s;
        position: relative;
    }
    .btn-three::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
        transition: all 0.3s;
    }
    .btn-three:hover::before {
        opacity: 0 ;
        transform: scale(0.5,0.5);
    }
    .btn-three::after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 0.3s;
        border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
        transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
    }
    .btn-three:hover::after {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1,1);
    }
```

Whenever I change the opacity of the background of the button to lets say completely black, the text completely disappears in the :before state.

Any reason for this? Seems like the text is in the same 'layer' as the button, instead of on top of it

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: @Paulie_D you're completely right! I will take it into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to move the anchor link outside your button tags and use z-index to force the text to the front.

CSS:

```
.btn-three {
  transition: all 0.5s;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 25px;
  height: 50px;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 250px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


.btn-three::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: rgba(16, 84, 35, 1);
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
.btn-three:hover::before {
    opacity: 0 ;
    transform: scale(0.5,0.5);
}
.btn-three::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
    z-index: 2;
}

.three-text {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -10px;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
}

.btn-three:hover::after {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1,1);
}

.button-wrapper {
    padding-top: 3%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 3%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="button-wrapper">
  <button class="btn btn-three" />
  <a class="three-text">HERE YOUR TEXT</a>
 </div>
```

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/cornest_/pen/yLYxXpK)

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the black opacity and have the text all the way to the front then you will need to "force" the text to the front with z-index

```
.btn-three span {
    z-index: 2; 
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;   
}

.btn-three::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

Without setting the span above the div your text will always fall behind it because your z-index for your `::before` state is set above the text.

This will always make it disappear, setting the z-index to -1 will send it to the back but it will no longer render your block black

```
.btn-three::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
```